# Laravel 5.2 Auth::login not persisting logged user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an authentication system which has also social login using Socialite.

The problem is when I use `Auth::login()` to log in the user when successfully authenticated from social media, the session doesn't persist after redirecting.

Though I am using the `web` middleware

here is my code in `routes.php`

```php
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Frontend', 'middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
    Route::get('login/{provider?}', 'AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('login/callback/google', 'AuthController@getGoogleCallback');
    Route::get('login/callback/facebook', 'AuthController@getFacebookCallback');    
});
```

and when the user is successfully authenticated in Facebook for example, I use this in my controller

```php
Auth::login($user);
return redirect()->to('/');
```

but after redirecting it gives me `null`

I also moved my `User.php` to `app/Models/User.php` and made all the necessary changes in `config/auth.php`.

Comment: What are you using as session driver? (check your `.env`)

Comment: Have you done a `composer dump-autoload` after creating the new folder/namespace? Are you referencing the namespace correctly? Have you checked your `storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the middleware = auth for your main route.

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Frontend', 'middleware' => ['web','auth'], function () {
     Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');    
});
```

Basically your main route should have an auth middleware but not other routes as the guest users will need to be able to access to login page.