# Logged in user(admin) getting Auth::guest() : true in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I'm implementing user and admin login function with different routes.
I just modified user routes to make admin routes.

**My routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome');

Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'admin', // "namespace" => ], function() {
  Route::get('/login', 'AdminAuthController@showLoginForm');
  Route::post('/login', 'AdminAuthController@login'); 
  Route::get('/logout', 'AdminAuthController@logout'); 
  Route::get('/home', 'AdminHomeController@index'); 
  });

php artisan route:list

|        | GET|HEAD | admin/home                   |                      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminHomeController@index                  | web,auth:admin  |
|        | POST     | admin/login                  |                      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminAuthController@login                  | web,guest:admin |
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/login                  |                      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminAuthController@showLoginForm          | web,guest:admin |
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/logout                 |                      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminAuthController@logout                 | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                         |                      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                       | web,auth:user   |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                        |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm          | web,guest:user  |
|        | POST     | login                        |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login                  | web,guest:user  |
|        | GET|HEAD | logout                       |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout                 | web             |
|        | POST     | password/email               |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail | web,guest       |
|        | POST     | password/reset               |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@reset              | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token?}      |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm      | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD | register                     |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm   | web,guest:user  |
|        | POST     | register                     |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register               | web,guest:user  |
```

I added admin guard.

Now I can login as user and admin but when I am in home view I still get Auth::guest => true. So I can't exactly get the view that I want.

```
app.blade.php
...
@if (Auth::guest())
         <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
         <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
@else
         <li class="dropdown">
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                 {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
           </a>

           <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
@endif
....
```

is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Try `Auth::guard('admin')->guest()`.

Comment: Can you show your routes.php file?

Comment: `Route::get('/', function () {
          return view('welcome');
      });`                                                      
           `Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'admin',
//    "namespace" =>
], function() {
  Route::get('/login', 'AdminAuthController@showLoginForm');
  Route::post('/login', 'AdminAuthController@login');
  Route::get('/logout', 'AdminAuthController@logout');
  Route::get('/home', 'AdminHomeController@index');
});`            
Route::auth();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');`

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen I get this error `Trying to get property of non-object` maybe it's null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Frontend', 'middleware' => ['web','auth'], function () {
     Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');    
});
```

Your middleware needs something like example above. Need a web and auth

see here for another answer [Laravel 5.2 Auth::login not persisting logged user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310628/laravel-5-2-authlogin-not-persisting-logged-user?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea what to do anymore

Comment: No problem, had the same error for about three days once, just wasn't referencing the web middleware